# How to create relationship in django model for postgresql database as per my design

Tags: django, django-models, postgresql-11

How to create relationship in django model for postgresql database as per my design. I want to create multiple forignkey relationship between two table as per given image.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


class Table1(models.Model):
    Emp_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Emp_ID_Emp_Ext= models.IntegerField()
    Emp_ID= models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    Exp_Ext= models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField()

class Table2(models.Model):
    File_ID = models.IntegerField()
    Emp_ID= models.IntegerField()
    Exp_Ext= models.IntegerField()
    Contant= ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField()))
    Date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to connect Emp_ID from table1 to Emp_ID table2 as well as Emp_Ext from table1 to Emp_Ext table2 as per the image diagram shows. I don't know whether I connect these two field with foreign key or composite key [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqc1L.png)

Comment: What does this mean? Do you want Emp_ID and Emp_Ext to point to *different rows* in the target table?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just want to make a multiple foreign key relationship between two tables table1 and table2 on cascade delete like Emp_ID of table1 will be the foreign key of table2 of column Emp_ID and same for Emp_Ext of table1 to foreign key relationship with table2 of column Emp_ext.